How can I switch from MAG to TRU heading in a 737?
I was reading the section in the FCOM for the 737 MAX concerning the heading display on the bottom of the PFD. It stated that it displays whether the current heading mode is magnetic or true, and the symbology that appears. However, I could not find any place that would allow the pilot to switch between these modes. Is this something a pilot can do, or is it performed internally? If it is performed by a pilot, how do they do it?

This switch is part of the Heading Reference System available only for customers who bought the Polar Operations option.
As the PDMG 737 MAX add-on is not yet available I assume this is for the 737 NG. It seems there are not many 737 NG flying over the poles, and I can't find a picture of the switch.This is where it is on a 757 (see also this):

Source.
Without the option operations at latitudes near or higher than 80° are not possible, as indicated in the 737 Dispatch Deviations Guide (DDG):

In order to conduct polar operations, the HDG REF switch must be installed, and one FMC, one CDU, and GPS-L must be operational for dispatch.

TRUE headings are required at high latitudes, the magnetic declination being not reliable. More.

That picture looks like it's from a 757 or 767, but definitely not a 737 MAX. Are you sure the switch would be located there on the MAX as well?

@Bianfable: No I'm not. Do you have additional information?

No, unfortunately not. As you say, these options are pretty rare for a 737, but I guess some Canadian 737s might have it equipped.

On the 737, it is a customer option associated with polar operations and, if fitted, will be on the overhead just above the window heat switches. If you are interested in polar operations you might find this link interesting: Boeing Polar Operations

Very interesting article.  What year is it from, please?

@RalphJ I think it was originally published in Boeing's "Aero" magazine in 2001.

A reference for the switch location?
